# Extract outer html from react element

Tags: html, reactjs, svg

```
const group = <g className="box" transform="translate(-13,147) rotate(45, 240, 80)"></g>;
```

I have defined group as shown above.
Here group is an svg group element. So now I have to calculate the transform matrix and all.
But when doing `console.log(group)` it is showing this:

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "g", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)key: nullprops: {className: "bbox", transform: "translate(-13,147) rotate(45, 240, 80)"}ref: nulltype: "g"_owner: null_store: {validated: false}_self: null_source: null__proto__: Object
```

I am expecting `<g className="bbox" transform="translate(-13,147) rotate(45, 240, 80)"></g>`. So how can I extract the html part from it.
Or I have to defined it in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ReactDOM` module for this:

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.findDOMNode(group);
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer? You get an exception? You get something unexpected?

Comment: the error messge is : Element appears to be neither ReactComponent nor DOMNode (keys: $$typeof,type,key,ref,props,_owner,_store) @Luca Fabbri

Comment: Sorry, I missed it was a `g` SVG native element, not a component.
This works on components and the element must be mounted in the DOM. See https://codesandbox.io/s/48lolx9l7x.
Note: you can also rely on the old-good `getElementById`

Comment: In react, we can't use getElementById and I want to access g in its siblings comoponent not into its its same component.I have fix it assigning a state variable to the parent class.